# Cherry picking a commit from a branch rebased to a different commit pulls in more history than desired

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I have a branch structure like follows. 3 branches.

```
a - b - c - d  *main*
     \
      e - f    *feature1*
           \
            h  *feature2*
```

I was originally developing `feature1` and then I started developing `feature2`. `feature2` actually does not rely on code changes from `feature1` but I wanted to be able to test them together. Figuring that `feature1` would get on `main` before `feature2`.

Plans changed. Now `feature2` is going to come in first. So what I want to do is essentially `cherry-pick` commit `h` into main.

When I look at the diff for `h` it is perfect. The changes on h are precisely what I want. Again `feature1` and `feature2` do not rely on each other from a code standpoint just testing/development standpoint.

The problem is when I am on `main` trying to `cherry-pick` in commit `h` it does not just bring in commit `h`. Commit `e` and `f` are in there too. I don't think they are like actually in there but since lines have merge conflicts when I am resolving those merge conflicts e and f are there.

Why is this happening? How can I get around this? Is there some requirement of the branches that you are cherry picking to/from.

Comment: I think you need to provide some example commands and output, because I do not believe this statement: "The problem is when I am on main trying to cherry-pick in commit h it does not just bring in commit h. Commit e and f are in there too." That should not be the case, if you did what you think you did.

Comment: Your edit just answered your own question, "I don't think they are like actually in there but since lines have merge conflicts when I am resolving those merge conflicts e and f are there." That's exactly right. The merge conflict is showing you additional context around what you changed in `h`, from that commit's point of view, to help you decide how to resolve the conflicts. It's up to you whether or not to include that additional context when you resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do either of the following:

- from main

```
git cherry-pick -x h
```

- from `feature2`

```
git rebase --onto main f feature2
```

The second would work if you had MORE than just `h` and didnt want to do multiple cherry picks.
It will put `h'` and any other commits after h' on feature2 ontop of `d` on `main`.

The first command should cherry pick the commit `h'` based upon `h` onto `main` after `d'` and it should denote where it come from in the commit message which many people find handy.

Comment: Although I agree with everything you said in this answer, I don't think this actually answers the question. OP claims they did your first option with the cherry-pick of `h`. So the question is "Why didn't that work?", which, IMHO we can't answer yet.

Comment: Hey so created a simpler git repository to make sure I could reproduce this. Realized it's more of an issue with the conflicts I think. For the most part the cherry pick worked but for lines that conflicted the conflict is between the line state on h and the line state on d. The line state of h includes the history of e and f and this is what makes it seem like those commits were pulled in.

Comment: based on the original question it was what i could suggest to clearly get `e` and `f` out.. it sounds like OP has miscommunicated when he said "`e` and `f` were in there" per his later messages. If OP wants to delete the question I am happy to delete the answer since it seems like it might not be salvageable into a good question at this point... let me know @CalebK   Appreciate the comment @TTT